# Connecting to SQL Server named instance without DNS resolution using hosts file

Tags: sql-server, dns, connection-string, hosts

I am hoping to get some input on a configuration challenge I am having with a connection string connecting to a named SQL server instance when DNS resolution is not available.

What I have is a third party application that gets a connection string injected into a web.config file via a configuration utility. The configuration uses the server-name\instance-name format to connect to SQL server.

However, the server itself does not have the ability to resolve the name via DNS so it will not work. I can get the database connection working by using the IP address and unfortunately I cannot change the instance name that gets pushed to the web.config file.

I am trying to avoid having this break and need to be manually adjusted any time the configuration gets pushed.

What I am hoping to do is utilize the hosts file to get the connection working properly, but maybe there is another solution.

The database is a named instance, but is using the default port so in my hosts file I am able to add this:

`Server-IP Server-Name`

and then in my web.config use just the server name server-name in the connection string data source to make a connection.

However, the configuration will always push the data source as server-name\instance-name so I need to somehow get that additional instance name working in my local resolution.

I did try in the hosts file:

`Server-Ip Server-Name\Instance-Name`

but that did not work. Also server-name\instance-name in the connection string does not work with just the server-name in the hosts file.

As a reference all of the following will work in the connection string without anything in the hosts file:

`Server-IP`
`Server-IP,Port`
`Server-IP,Port\InstanceName`

but the only thing I can get working is server-name only in the hosts file and connection string.

Comment: Instance names are not resolved in DNS. There is a SQL Browser service on the target server listening on udp/1434 - the client uses the SQL Server Resolution Protocol to query that service and resolve the instance name to the actual TCP port that it's listening on, then establishes the SQL connection using the resolved TCP port. Therefore network firewalls and host firewalls have to allow udp/1434 access for SSRP queries as well as the actual listening TCP ports for MS-TDS connections.

Comment: Ah, very informative thank you. I will see if opening that port up will get it working without the IP.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by AlwaysLearning in the comments, the solution was to allow udp/1434 access for SSRP queries.